Angular Js Id convert to other formate
I'm using Angular js now I'm Facing error when button is click it will fire a function
and this function is pass a value it will convert the value in like this  : 1e+21 but the actual value is like this  : **01E000002M **
enter image description here
enter image description here
HERE is my Code :
enter image description here
@using RamaReports.Entity;
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Student Details";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<div class="right_col" role="main" ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="LmsStudentCtrl">
    <div class="">
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="x_panel">
                    <div class="x_title">
                        <h2>Student</h2>
                        <div class="clearfix"> (kindly select atleast one parameter value)</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="x_content">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="control-label col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                       Student Name:
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                        <input type="text" id="txtnamefilter" ng-model="EmpName" class="form-control" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="control-label col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                        Location:
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                        <select id="ddllocation" ng-model="ddlLocation" class="form-control" ng-change="LocationChange()">
                                            <option ng-repeat="c in Location" value="{{c.Value}}">{{c.Text}}</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                <div class="=form-group">
                                    <div class="control-label col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                        Institute:
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                        <select id="ddlcompany" ng-model="ddlCompany" class="form-control" ng-change="CompanyChange()">
                                            <option ng-repeat="c in Company" value="{{c.Value}}">{{c.Text}}</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="control-label col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                    Department
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                    <select id="ddldepartment" ng-model="ddlDepartment" class="form-control" ng-change="DepartmentChange()">
                                        <option ng-repeat="c in Department" value="{{c.Value}}">{{c.Text}}</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="control-label col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                    Program:
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                    <select id="ddldesignation" ng-model="ddlDesignation" class="form-control">
                                        <option ng-repeat="c in Designation" value="{{c.Value}}">{{c.Text}}</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="control-label col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                    Session:
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                    <select id="ddlemployementtype" ng-model="ddlEmployementType" class="form-control">
                                        <option ng-repeat="c in EmployementType" value="{{c.Value}}">{{c.Text}}</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                                &nbsp;
                                <input type="button" id="btnfilter" ng-click="EmployeeList()" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary" />
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <table id="datatable-responsive" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Action</th>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>EmployeeCode</th>
                                <th>Location</th>
                                <th>Company</th>
                                <th>Department</th>
                                <th>Designation</th>

                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody></tbody>
                    </table>
                    <input type="button" id="btnopenmmodal" data-target="#dvModalForm" style="display:none;" data-toggle="modal" />
                    <div id="dvModalForm" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                        <div class="modal-dialog">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                    <h4 class="modal-title">Details</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                                                <div class="panel panel-primary">
                                                    <div class="panel-heading">Personal Detail</div>
                                                    <div class="panel-body">
                                                        <div class="profile clearfix">
                                                            @*<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,{{empimage}}" alt="..." class="img-circle profile_img" style="height:56px;width: 56px;">*@
                                                            <table id="datatable-personal" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0">
                                                                <thead>
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <th colspan="2">{{empname.EmpName}}</th>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                </thead>
                                                                <tbody>
                                                                    <tr><td>Location : </td><td><span>{{empname.Location_name}}</span></td></tr>
                                                                    <tr><td>Company :</td><td>{{empname.company_name}}                </td></tr>
                                                                    <tr><td>Department :</td><td>{{empname.Department_Name}}          </td></tr>
                                                                    <tr><td>Designation :</td><td>{{empname.Designation_Name}}        </td></tr>
                                                                    <tr><td>Biometric Id :</td><td>{{empname.biometrics_id}}          </td></tr>
                                                                    <tr><td>DOB :</td><td>{{empname.date_of_birth}}          </td></tr>
                                                                </tbody>
                                                            </table>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-5 col-sm-12">
                                                <div class="panel panel-primary">
                                                    <div class="panel-heading">Contact</div>
                                                    <div class="panel-body">
                                                        <table id="datatable-contact" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0">
                                                            <thead>
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <th></th>
                                                                    <th></th>
                                                                </tr>
                                                            </thead>
                                                            <tbody>
                                                                <tr><td>Father :</td><td>{{empname.father_name}}   </td></tr>
                                                                <tr><td>Phone :</td><td>{{empname.phone_no}}            </td></tr>
                                                                <tr><td>Mobile :</td><td>{{empname.mobile_no}}          </td></tr>
                                                                <tr><td>Pan :</td><td>{{empname.pan_no}}                </td></tr>
                                                                <tr><td>Adhar :</td><td>{{empname.emp_adhaar_no}}       </td></tr>
                                                                <tr><td>Email :</td><td>{{empname.email_id}}            </td></tr>
                                                                <tr><td>Off. Email :</td><td>{{empname.official_email}} </td></tr>
                                                                <tr><td>Address :</td><td>{{empname.Address}}           </td></tr>
                                                                <tr><td>City :</td><td>{{empname.city}}                 </td></tr>
                                                            </tbody>
                                                        </table>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-3 col-sm-12">
                                                <div class="panel panel-primary">
                                                    <div class="panel-heading">Salary</div>
                                                    <div class="panel-body">
                                                        <table id="datatable-salary" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                                            <thead>
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <th>Effctive Date</th>
                                                                    <th>Salary Type</th>
                                                                    <th>Salary</th>
                                                                </tr>
                                                            </thead>
                                                            <tbody></tbody>
                                                        </table>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                                                <div class="panel panel-primary">
                                                    <div class="panel-heading">KPA</div>
                                                    <div class="panel-body">
                                                        <table id="datatable-kpa" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                                            <thead>
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <th>KPA</th>
                                                                    <th>KPA Goal</th>
                                                                    <th>Wightage</th>
                                                                </tr>
                                                            </thead>
                                                            <tbody></tbody>
                                                        </table>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    var hostUrl = $("#hdnAppRoot").val();
    var AngularApp = angular.module("MyApp", []);
    //AngularApp.controller("HrmsEmpCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {
    AngularApp.controller('LmsStudentCtrl', ['$scope', '$compile', function ($scope, $compile, $http) {
        $scope.empname = [];
        $scope.Location = [];
        $scope.Company = [{ Text: " --Select--", Value: "0" }]
        $scope.ddlCompany = $scope.Company[0].Value.toString();
        $scope.Department = [{ Text: " --Select--", Value: "0" }]
        $scope.ddlDepartment = $scope.Department[0].Value.toString();
        $scope.Designation = [{ Text: " --Select--", Value: "0" }]
        $scope.ddlDesignation = $scope.Designation[0].Value.toString();

        $scope.EmployeeList = function () {
            var t = { EmpName: $scope.EmpName, LocationId: $scope.ddlLocation, CompanyId: $scope.ddlCompany, DepartmentId: $scope.ddlDepartment, DesignationId: $scope.ddlDesignation, EmployementTypeId: $scope.ddlEmployementType, emp_id: 0 }
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '' + hostUrl + '/Home/StudentDetailsList',
                data: t,
                success: function (empdate) {
                    var dataforTable = empdate;
                    $('#datatable-responsive').DataTable({
                        //paging: true,
                        //searching: true,
                        destroy: true,
                        data: dataforTable,
                        //scroll:true,
                        columns: [
                            {
                                title: "Action", render: function (datum, type, row) {
                                    return "<button type='button' class='btn btn-danger btn-xs'  ng-click='EmpDetails(" + row.emp_id + ")'><i class='fa fa-trash-o'></i>Details</button>";
                                }
                            },

                                { title: "Location", data: "Location_name" },
                                { title: "RUM No", data: "EmpSalary" },
                                { title: "Student Name", data: "company_name" },
                               
                                { title: "Father Name", data: "father_name" },
                                { title: "Year", data: "Department_Name" },
                                { title: "Semster", data: "pan_no" },
                                

                        ],
                        createdRow: function (row, data, dataIndex) {
                            $compile(angular.element(row).contents())($scope);
                        }
                    });
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                }
            });
        }

        $scope.LocationDropdown = function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '' + hostUrl + '/Home/HrmsDropdown',
                data: { Flag: "LoctionLMS", Id: 0 },
                success: function (mRes) {
                    console.log(mRes);
                    $scope.$apply(function () { $scope.Location = mRes; $scope.ddlLocation = $scope.Location[0].Value.toString(); })
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                }
            });
        }
        $scope.LocationDropdown();

        $scope.LocationChange = function () {
            debugger;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '' + hostUrl + '/Home/HrmsDropdownLMS',
                data: { Flag: "LMSDivision", Id: $scope.ddlLocation },
                success: function (mRes) {
                    $scope.$apply(function () {
                        $scope.Company = mRes;
                        $scope.ddlCompany = $scope.Company[0].Value.toString();
                    })
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                }
            });
        }


        $scope.CompanyChange = function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '' + hostUrl + '/Home/HrmsDropdownLMS',
                data: { Flag: "LMSDepartment", Id: $scope.ddlCompany },
                success: function (mRes) {
                    $scope.$apply(function () {
                        $scope.Department = mRes;
                        $scope.ddlDepartment = $scope.Department[0].Value.toString();
                    })
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                }
            });

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '' + hostUrl + '/Home/HrmsDropdownLMS',
                data: { Flag: "Session", Id: $scope.ddlCompany },
                success: function (mRes) {
                    $scope.$apply(function () { $scope.EmployementType = mRes; $scope.ddlEmployementType = $scope.EmployementType[0].Value.toString(); })
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                }
            });
        }



        $scope.DepartmentChange = function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '' + hostUrl + '/Home/HrmsDropdownLMS',
                data: { Flag: "LMSProgram", Id: $scope.ddlDepartment },
                success: function (mRes) {
                    $scope.$apply(function () {
                        $scope.Designation = mRes;
                        $scope.ddlDesignation = $scope.Designation[0].Value.toString();
                    })
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                }
            });
        }

        debugger;
        //01E000002M

        $scope.EmpDetails = function (emp_id) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '' + hostUrl + '/Home/HrmsEmployeeImage',
                data: { LocationId: "0", CompanyId: "0", DepartmentId: "0", DesignationId: "0", EmployementTypeId: "0", emp_id: emp_id },
                success: function (empdate) {
                    $scope.$apply(function () { $scope.empname = empdate[0] });
                    $("#btnopenmmodal").click();
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                }
            });

            debugger;

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '' + hostUrl + '/Home/HrmsEmployeeImage',
                data: { emp_id: emp_id },
                success: function (empsalary) {
                    var dataforTable = empsalary;
                    $('#datatable-salary').DataTable({
                        paging: false,
                        searching: false,
                        destroy: true,
                        data: dataforTable,
                        columns: [

                          //  { title: "salaryType", data: "salaryType" },
                          //  { title: "seffectiveDate", data: "seffectiveDate" },
                          //  { title: "EffectiveDateSlry", data: "EffectiveDateSlry" }

                        ],
                            createdRow: function (row, data, dataIndex) {
                            $compile(angular.element(row).contents())($scope);
                        }
                    });
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                }
            });

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '' + hostUrl + '/Home/HrmsEmployeeImage',
                data: { emp_id: emp_id },
                success: function (empdate) {
                    $scope.$apply(function () { $scope.empimage = empdate[0].image });
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                }
            });

            debugger;

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '' + hostUrl + '/Home/StudentList',
                data: { emp_id: emp_id },
                success: function (empsalary) {
                    var dataforTable = empsalary;
                    $('#datatable-kpa').DataTable({
                        paging: false,
                        searching: false,
                        destroy: true,
                        data: dataforTable,
                        columns: [
                            { title: "KPA", data: "KPA" },
                            { title: "KPA Goal", data: "KPA_Goal" },
                            { title: "Weightage", data: "KPA_Weightage" }
                        ],
                        createdRow: function (row, data, dataIndex) {
                            $compile(angular.element(row).contents())($scope);
                        }
                    });
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                }
            });
        }
    }]);

</script>


i try to convert string  but no solution.

columns: [
    {
        title: "Action", render: function (datum, type, row) {
            return "<button type='button' class='btn btn-danger btn-xs' ng-click=\"EmpDetails('" + row.emp_id + "')\"><i class='fa fa-trash-o'></i>Details</button>";
        }
    },

i use this it is working
